# Two way binding in a loop

Tags: jquery

I stumbled upon an interesting example where a loop is created involving 4 div's http://jsfiddle.net/w5YHY/2/

```
var $elements = $('#One, #Two, #Three, #Four');
    $elements.eq(i).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((i + 1));
        }, 3000);
    });
```

The loop works fine.

I had the following queries in my mind.

Each radio button corresponds to a div. If the loop is at position 3, radio 3 should be selected and so on. How is this done? Vice-versa the radio should manipulate the loop, something like a 2-way binding.

Moreover clicking the left and right buttons should also change the loop. So assume the loop is at position 3 and the left button is clicked, it should go back to 2.

How can I do all these event bindings elegantly without repeating code?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8bNr/2/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I found a bug in your code. Help me fix it please. When the loop reaches 4th radio, I have to click the Right button twice to make it move to the next element. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<button id="left" data-dir="-1">Left</button>
<button id="right" data-dir="1">right</button>
```

then

```
var $elements = $('#One, #Two, #Three, #Four');
var $radios = $('input[name="op"]');

var timer;
function anim_loop(index) {
    if(timer){
        $elements.filter('.current').stop(true, true).hide().removeClass('current');
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
    $radios.eq(index).prop('checked', true);
    $elements.eq(index).stop(true, true).addClass('current').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('current');
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            timer = undefined;
        }, 3000);
    });
}

$radios.click(function(){
    anim_loop($radios.index(this));
});

$('#left, #right').click(function () {
    var index = $elements.index($elements.filter('.current')) + $(this).data('dir');
    anim_loop(index % $elements.length)
})

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8bNr/)

Comment: Nice! The right button behaves strange when the loop is at the last index. Can you also add comments to the code to help me understand what you are doing here.

Comment: Bugger, I was just finishing up a very similar solution but you've beat me to it, oh well...

Comment: @KayKay have you gone through the code? did you understand it

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did follow some of it. If you could add comments to the jsfiddle itself, that'd be great Here's the fiddle I am following jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m8bNr/2

Comment: Thanks. My colleague helped me find yet another bug. Just when the loop is moving from 3rd to 4th radio and 4th starts getting selected, immediately click on 2. A strange thing happens! The text below the radio gets overlapped and the loop instead of going from 2 to 3, now goes back to 1. Try clicking the right button quickly and same thing happens. Not sure why

Comment: @KayKay what do you want to do if the user clicks on a radio when there is already a transition between 2 elements in progress

Comment: IMHO if the radio is transitioning between 3 to 4 and user clicks on 1, it should honor the user selection and move to 1. Do you feel the same?

Comment: @KayKay yes... we need to abort the current transition and move to the user selection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48172/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-kaykay)